# Windows 'move' command's /y not overriding destiation file, failing with an error: file already exists

Tags: wine

In wine and wineconsole when I try and move a file with the following command:

`move /Y "file" "destination"` I get the following error:

File already exists

and the file is not replaced.  According to the windows help page http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490935.aspx /y should suppress the prompt asking if you wish to override the file, which it does, and also overwrite the file, which it fails at.

If I don't use /y it prompts me, after responding yes the file is overwritten.  Can someone confirm the move command with /y is broken in wine (v1.6) and if so offer any suggestions while still using the move command.

Comment: What is your "wine" version ? seems that a bug has been reported for your specific issue : http://wine.1045685.n5.nabble.com/PATCH-1-3-cmd-move-issues-when-overwriting-files-td5724962.html

Comment: Ah so it is, it's version 1.6.  Updated the questions with additional info.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary fix I perform a `del /f/q` on the destination before I move the file.